# jQuery conflict between a lightbox function and masonry/endless scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, endlessscroll

I wanted to create a lightbox effect for images when clicked, so eventually I found [this tutorial](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/super-simple-lightbox-with-css-and-jquery--webdesign-3528) and followed all the necessary steps to insert it into my page (with a little modification).

The lightbox functions exactly the way I want it to, but the jQuery library used for the lightbox is conflicting with another script and it's messing up the multi-column layout and endless scroll.

[This is a mock page with the lightbox effect.](http://sharongongart.tumblr.com) Normally, all the posts should be scattered in a lose multi-column fashion and new posts should load with endless scroll.

I tried deleting a bunch of things to see where the conflict was, and these are the two scripts that conflict.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/twte3d7/4Wjm5wj58/disassemble_v3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery needs to be the first script you include.
*jQuery Masonry* extends *jQuery* so you must reference the jQuery library first.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/twte3d7/4Wjm5wj58/disassemble_v3.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried that and masonry worked, but the lightbox did not. But thanks so much for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple IDs on divs containing images

```
<div id="post">
   <img src="">
</div>
```

what if you put class instead of id?
And could you provide an example of your masonry implementation?

Thanks

Comment: I tried that and it didn't make a difference :( And I honestly have no idea, the layout is a Tumblr theme that I modified. But thank you for your help!